# mapping network drive, sh.exe": no such file or directory

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I'm trying to learn to use the command line and I googled on how to map network drives from the command line.  I came across using the net command and the pushd command.  We have a mapped network drive at work that I can go to in Windows Explorer by doing

```
\\sf-testers\test-datasets\
```

When I try

```
pushd \\sf-testers\test-datasets\
```

I get the response:

```
sh.exe": pushd: \sf-testers\test-datasets: No such file or directory
```

When I try

```
net use x: \\sf-testers\test-datasets
```

I get:

```
System error 67 has occurred.
The network name cannot be found.
```

I'm running Windows 7 on bootcamp.  What am I doing incorrectly?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer to [kb 843156](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/843156) in regards to the 2nd error. Also you cannot pushd to a network location you first need to map the network location to a drive then pushd to that drive

Comment: @50-3 So I first mapped the \\sf-testers\test-datasets\ to my x:.  I then tried the same pushd command listed above.  I still get the same response about no such file or directory.  Any other thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: To confirm you successfully map x: and then the command `pushd x:\ ` is failing? what is the error?

Comment: @50-3 Yes when I click on the x: through windows explorer, I can see the datasets I'm interested in.  When I run the pushd \\sf-testers\test-datasets, I get sh.exe": pushd: \sf-testerstest-datasets: No such file or directory

Comment: can you `pushd x:\ ` if  \\sf-testers\test-datasets\ is a valid path pushd should just assign it a temp drive letter but would like to know if you can pushd to a drive - also do you know what sh.exe is as this isn't something that should be outputted using standard power shell or command prompt